# Python packaging with demo

Tags: python, python-packaging

I've a question about python packaging.
My project is a library and I would like to have a demo of how to use this library in the form of an application with GUI.

I'm thinking of doing the following by using the **install_requires** from setuptools:

- 1 package for the library
- 1 package for the demo with GUI (auto installed when the 1st package is or that installs the library if the demo is installed)

Is that overkilled or is a decent way to approach it?
Basically I don't want to bloat my library with an entire demo application.

***edit:***

I probably need to give a bit more context to explain the situation better.

Basically my Library is an API to represent data and interact with it. But since I’m only offering the representation part, it doesn’t actually do anything when you interact with it.

The idea behind the demo is to create an entire environment in the form of an application that will provide contextual data to represent -> represent it -> then connect it to the environment so that when the user interacts with the representation it actually does something such as modifying the data for example.

so in that demo, most of the content is context based and irrelevant to the Library and that’s what i’m referring to when I say clutter / bloat. it’s only there to provide a context to the user and have finished product that actually does something when they test it.

Also I realize that over time I could grow that demo even more to show more possibilities of implementation without having to change the library.

That’s why I want to separate it.

So basically I want to always install the latest compatible version of the demo when the library is installed and also potentially be able to separately update the demo to the latest version if needed.

I hope this make sense :)

Cheers,

Comment: if you want to auto install GUI when you install library then why to split it ?

Comment: I like when library has some built-in functionality and can be run with option `-m` like `python -m http.server` to run HTTP server.

Comment: the GUI is a big chunk of code that serves no purpose other than being a demo. I don't want that code to cluter up the library.

Comment: @Goffer Do you mean something like [extras](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-setuptools-extras)?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with packaging as it's the 1st time I'm going to do it. I wanted to use the install_requires to install my demo. But it looks like extras is similar.

Comment: Ok, I wrote an answer with what I would consider the most common approach. What you wrote in your question sounds completely valid as well, though.

Answer (score 1):

If a package provides some kind of optional feature that isn't part of the core functionality, it is usually gated with [`extras`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies). This only addresses the dependencies your project has, the demo code would always be part of your library. That's usually ok though, because dependencies are where the really big chunks of bandwidth get wasted on.

Just to have an example to go on, the popular `pyparsing` package offers in its version 3 an extra called `diagrams`. The code to make diagrams work is part of the codebase and will be downloaded when installing pyparsing even without the extra. But its ~400 lines of code are [nicely split off the core](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/tree/master/pyparsing/diagram)  so that it can't possibly interfere with it. It's not clutter if it can safely be ignored.

The additional packages needed to make it work are a different story. On my machine, running `pip install pyparsing==3.0.0a2` takes up 648kB of space. Running `pip install pyparsing[diagrams]==3.0.0a2` adds 1872kB total, nearly three times as much. And this isn't even an extreme example, it just happened to be the last thing I installed which had an extra.

---

Summed up, if your optional feature doesn't introduce any additional dependencies, it's best practice to just include the feature. If it does introduce dependencies (e.g. some `gui_lib_for_demo`), split them off through extras, and maybe do something like this in your demo code

```py
try:
    import gui_lib_for_demo
except ImportError:
    print("If you want to run the demo, please install this library with "
          "`pip install my_lib[demo]` instead.")

# actual demo code starts here
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I've edited my question with more context. The demo doesn't introduce new dependencies though. Do you think **extras** is still the way to do it? or a combination of **extras** and **install_requires** Or do you think it still makes sense to add it directly to the Library?

Comment: In that case I'd just add the feature to the library, neither extras nor install requires will do anything unless you write the demo to be its own package which, as you also wrote, is in my opinion overkill. It is for sure a good idea to keep the demo code in its own submodule (read, folder) within your project, same as `pyparsing` does, so that you 1) reduce the cognitive load for someone who want to read the code of you project and 2) to reduce the probability of demo code being called by accident to ~0%.

Comment: Reading your edit gives a little more context. I think my opinion overall doesn't change, I'd still include the demo code in the project itself. But it seems to serve a documentation purpose, so it might be worth an idea to consider writing some additional documentation and referencing to parts of the demo in there, instead of having the demo be the documentation. Maybe you already know all this, but just in case: [a guide to doc-writing](https://www.writethedocs.org/guide/writing/beginners-guide-to-docs/), and [an intro to sphinx](https://opensource.com/article/19/11/document-python-sphinx).

Comment: The documentation with Sphinx is already planned. To me the demo is more of a different project using my Library project as an implementation example. I see it as an extra resource that's not needed to understand my project but that's there to show how it can be used. The documentation will be there to explain the library itself. Hence why I want to separate the demo

Comment: Sounds like you made up your mind - if the demo is a different project for you, then you should not distribute it with the library. Whether that'll be through its own package, as a script in the docs, or a blogpost is something you can evaluate best.